# How do I install PECL APD on wamp server?

Tags: php, pecl

How do I install PECL APD on wamp server so that I can profile my PHP scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your INI file, add the following lines:

```
zend_extension = /absolute/path/to/apd.so
apd.dumpdir = /absolute/path/to/trace/directory
apd.statement_tracing = 0
```

And download it from [this link](http://pecl.php.net/get/apd).

Depending on your PHP build, the zend_extension directive can be one of the following:

```
zend_extension              (non ZTS, non debug build)
zend_extension_ts           (    ZTS, non debug build)
zend_extension_debug        (non ZTS,     debug build)
zend_extension_debug_ts     (    ZTS,     debug build)
```

And then restart your server.